# Does JobTRacker know how much data is transfered to each reduce task during the shuffling phase before the actual data tranfer

Tags: hadoop, reducers

In Hadoop, can the JobTracker know how much data each ReduceTask has to retrieve (in shuffle phase) before the actual data movement? I am trying to collect statistics regarding data movement during the shuffling phase.

Answer (score 0):

In short: can it know - maybe, does it use this information - no.

Depending on your configuration for the `mapred.reduce.slowstart.completed.maps` configuration property, a reduce task can be started before the majority of the map tasks have completed, therefore the scheduler implementation does not take this information into account when scheduling reduce tasks.

It maybe that implementing your own scheduler, you can retrieve this information from some counter stats, but you'd have to dig through the source and i'm not sure you have access to the counters.

As an alternative, can you not utilize the map / reduce counters and / or the logs for the task attempts (maybe the task tracker logs too)?